# how to show element when mouse hold on it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one `ul` and many `li` in it. I want when mouse hold on in any `li` for 3 second show me one div and when I leave mouse from this element that div hide.
I many search in google and I understand that I should to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` but I don't know how to use from those.
also I want when click on any `li` show me one alert. please guide me because I'm so confused.

thanks a lot

this is my code:
**HTML:**

```
<ul id="friend-list">
        <li id="1"></li>
        <li id="2"></li>
        <li id="3"></li>
        <li id="4"></li>
        <li id="5"></li>
        <li id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#friend-list li',function(){
    $('#center-side').fadeIn('slow');
});
$(document).on('mouseout','#friend-list li',function(){
    $('#center-side').stop().fadeOut('slow');
});

$(document).on('click','#friend-list li',function(){
    alert('aaaaaaaaa');
});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried. No-one will write this for you.

Comment: Agreed. Set up a jsFiddle, and it'll be more likely somebody will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
                        var timer = null;
                        $('#friend-list li').hover(function() {
                            var $el = $('#center-side');
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                $el.css('display','block');
                            }, 1500);
                        }, function() {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#center-side').css('display','none');
                            }, 10);

                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout()`

**jQuery**

```
var tOut;

$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li', function () {
    tOut = setTimeout(function () {
        $('div').show();
    }, 3000);
}).on('mouseout', 'li', function () {
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    $('div').hide();
}).on('click','li',function(){
    alert("aaaaaaaaa");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<div>show and hide me</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kesq3/2/)

Comment: my friend I want when hold on element after 3 second show me and when mouse leave that element end show (hide)

Comment: That's what it does, hold over an element for 3 seconds and you will see that the div becomes visible and then move your mouse away the element will hide @mamal10

Comment: my friend I use this code but when I hold mouse on element for 3 second div is Blinker!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.foo").mouseover(function()
{
    $("div.foo").show(100);
}.mouseout(function()
{
    $("div.foo").hide(100);
}.click(function()
{
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: @Anton's answer is better as mine doesn't include the 3 second timeout

Answer (score 0):

jQuery -> mousedown

```
$(".element").mousedown(function(){
  alert("Success");
});
```

This will run your code, when user click down on the element. Mouseup -> when leave the click down.

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

```
$(".element").mouseenter(function(){
  alert("Enter");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  alert("Leave");
});
```

Whis will run your code just if the cursor is flying around the object, not click.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/